# MySQL variable setting through connection string or connection object?

Tags: c#, mysql, view, parameters, connection-string

This is a contrived example however I have simplified it for ease of explanation.

> Please see my update at the bottom before investing too much of your
> time!

### Background

I have some (a lot of) code that ordinarily queries my DB as follows:

`SELECT name FROM sites where IsLive=1;`

My challenge is to, under certain conditions, return the *full* list of sites, essentially

`SELECT name from sites;`

I do not wish to modify the actual C# code issuing the SQL (although I can do if I have to in order to achieve my goal which is purely for demonstration purposes).
Therefore in order to leave as much untouched as possible my thoughts are to insert a `database-proxy-view` called **site** that returns the data dependent on a `control variable`

### Method

1. Rename existing `site` table to `site_table`
2. Create a new **view** named `site` that the C# code now unknowingly targets and which returns the (possibly filtered) details from `site_table` according to the `control variable` value (Note a limitation on variables in views meant I had to create a function in order to demonstrate this - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html wrt error 1351)

### Changes made

1. `ALTER TABLE site RENAME TO site_table;`
2. `CREATE FUNCTION controlVariableFn() RETURNS VARCHAR(16) RETURN @controlVariable;`
3. `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW site AS SELECT * from site_table WHERE (IsLive = 1 OR controlVariableFn() = 'SHOWALL');`

The above statements are **ugly** but achieve the result I want, however my problem is to dynamically pass through `controlVariable` without changing my main SQL queries being sent.

## My Question

Is there a way to (ideally as I am creating my connection object) define the `controlVariable` outside the actual SQL to be executed but which the **View** can still access similar to the above as though it had been supplied as a regular user variable parameter to the query?

so the code would look something like

```
var connectionString = "Server=localhost;User ID=un;Password=pw;Database=dbname;....";
DbConnection db = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
                  (connectionString, "controlVariable=SHOWALL");
var results = db.Query<Site>("SELECT * FROM site;");
```

(I understand that this would not be a smart permanent solution)

---

> **Update**
> My preferred solution as outlined above will not work for me as once I get into my data access layer as the results set will
> essentially be filtered again back to the original set.  There are some circumstances where it
> could work; it would depend on the SQL issued (e.g. when collapsing a
> results set down instead of trying to expand a results set as I was
> trying to do here).
> In that regard I am no longer looking for an answer here but will leave it for posterity as a preferred option and as per the guidelines - thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to edit the c# code then the variable will have to be stored in the database although i am not sure how you will not edit the code.
If you are willing to edit the code then you can access a secondary configuration table which will have the settings that you would like the user to pass to the view. take this and allow the user to select which they want and then pass it to the view through the application.

Comment: Thanks @Shon - that is a useful suggestion and something that I did not think of, although I would need to correlate the subsequent queries against the stored variable, I am not sure how I would do that.  
I am able to edit the code, I'm just trying to avoid editing the _existing_ queries. So your idea would fit in with my criteria.

I did also wonder whether different classes of users could have different connection strings that give access to custom **site** views.  I shall think more about this and post back if it works.